# How to run scopt scala apllication

Tags: scala, command-line-interface, scopt

I am using this library to write cli application: https://github.com/scopt/scopt

I can run my application only inside sbt with command:
`run --foo 2 -b 1`

Ideally I would like to run my application in terminal like this:
`myapp --foo 2 -b 1` 
or this script :
`./myapp --foo 2 -b 1`

How can I do it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [**sbt-assembly**](https://github.com/sbt/sbt-assembly) to create a Fat jar than then you can run like:

```sh
java -jar path/to/app.jar --foo 2 -b 1
```

You can also use [**sbt-native-packager**](https://www.scala-sbt.org/sbt-native-packager/) to create an installer for your platform, after running the installer there will be a script in the `PATH` that will allow you to do:

```sh
app --foo 2 -b 1
```

But, under the hood, this is still calling `java -jar`
If you do not want to need to install a **JRE** on your target platform you can use [**sbt-native-image**](https://github.com/scalameta/sbt-native-image) *(which under the hood uses [**Graal**](https://www.graalvm.org/))* to create a native image of your app that could be run like any other binary.

```sh
./app --foo 2 -b 1
```