# Run compiled scala 3 code give java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: scala/util/CommandLineParser$ParseError

Tags: java, scala, sbt, scala-3

it may be a silly question from a scala newbie like myself.

I created the simple hello.scala using scala 3 syntax as follow:

```
@main def hello: Unit = 
  println("Hello world!")
  println(msg)

def msg = "I was compiled by Scala 3. :)"
```

Then, compile the code using this command `$scala3-compiler hello.scala`. This give me the .class stuff

```
>hello.class  
>Hello$package.class  
>hello.tasty  
>Hello$package.tasty  
>Hello$package$.class
```

Finally, I try to run this compiled files using `$java -cp . hello` which results in the error as follow:

```
Error: A JNI error has occurred, please check your installation and try again
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: scala/util/CommandLineParser$ParseError
```

How can I run this compiled files using java? It seems that the class CommandLineParser$ParseError is missing, but if I create the new project using `$sbt new scala/scala3.g8` then `$sbt run`
it can be run just fine. I wonder why.

P.S. I installed the scala using coursier which give me 2 versions of scala. If I typed `$scala --version` it returns the 2.13.6 scala versions.

Comment: You would need to put the stdlib jar in the CLASSPATH, that is usually just unnecessary, use **sbt** or any other build tool and call it a day. And if you are wondering how to distribute a project so it can be run without a build tool then refer to this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68102517/how-to-run-scopt-scala-apllication/68103334#68103334

Comment: Oh thanks! At first, I thought the classpath is just additional library to run altogether with standarad library.